# Playing audio from two data sources

Tags: java, array, comparative-review, audio, udp

I want to play some audio of two byte arrays. I was wondering whether it would be better to play them as two separate arrays both calling the method, or to put them into one array and play it from there.

**Note:** The starting from position 4 because the first 4 bytes are saved for the sequence number in the array.

All in one array:

```
   byte[] das = ByteBuffer.allocate((temp.length-4)*2)
                        .put(Arrays.copyOfRange(temp, 4, temp.length - 4))
                        .put(Arrays.copyOfRange(udpPacketBytes, 4, udpPacketBytes.length - 4))
                        .array();
                player.playBlock(das);
```

or split like this:

```
  byte[] filteredByteArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(temp, 4, temp.length - 4);

                player.playBlock(filteredByteArray);

                // play the current one
                byte[] fba = Arrays.copyOfRange(udpPacketBytes, 4, udpPacketBytes.length - 4);

                player.playBlock(fba);
```

I was also wondering whether there'd be a way to calculate the complexity of the two.

Comment: What kind of object is `player`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Implementation

`Better` is a nebulous concept. The first one assumes that both arrays are the same length and fails to play all audio otherwise, so I'll say that's worse. I would suggest pulling the subarray computation into a method.

```
private void playAudio(final byte[] audio) {
    this.player.playBlock(Arrays.copyOfRange(audio, 4, audio.length - 4));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so I'd just call this method twice in my case?

Comment: Yes, you would.

Comment: Had to move a few things around to get it to fit in my code, works great thanks